# Disable or toggle Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

What would be the best way to go about adding in a function for toggling the mailer in rails? The user would be able to perhaps click a button and all mails being sent out would be disabled/enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some kind of queue system, i.e, `resque`, `sidekick` i believe in the moment there are some jobs enqueued for mailing, you can kill the queue and dump these mails and whatever. I would research about Rails and queues. It's pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Ah, alright. Thank you! Do you know if there's another way besides having a queue system? perhaps some kind of mailer function in rails that can turn off all outgoing mails?

Comment: I don't know man. Mailers acts request based, so there's no way more than one mail is being sent by the same user at the same time.